# Toast in Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying a simple code to display caller number as toast whenever a call is received.

I get the following error:

```
 03-11 13:34:41.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27141): java.lang.NullPointerException
 03-11 13:34:41.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27141):   at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:93)
 03-11 13:34:41.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27141):   at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
 03-11 13:34:41.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27141):   at com.demotest.ringer.PhoneListenerBroad$MyPhoneStateListener.onCallStateChanged(PhoneListenerBroad.java:47)
 03-11 13:34:41.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27141):   at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:369)
 03-11 13:34:41.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27141):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 03-11 13:34:41.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27141):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 03-11 13:34:41.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27141):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 03-11 13:34:41.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27141):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-11 13:34:41.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27141):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 03-11 13:34:41.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27141):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 03-11 13:34:41.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27141):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 03-11 13:34:41.143: E/AndroidRuntime(27141):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is the code I am trying:

```
 public class PhoneListenerBroad extends BroadcastReceiver  
  { 
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    try 
    {
        // TELEPHONY MANAGER class object to register one listner
        TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        //Create Listner
        MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();

        // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
        tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
    }

}

private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener 
{
    private Context context;

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
    {

        Log.e("MyPhoneListener",state+"   incoming no:"+incomingNumber);

        if (state == 1) 
        {
            String msg = "New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : "+incomingNumber;
            Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Manifest has required permissions and declarations.. I am not sure where I am going wrong?

Comment: what is your 93 line?

Comment: Debug and check incomingNumber having any value??

Comment: Yep. Log shows the number.

Comment: I don't have any 93 line. total 51 lines including the import.

Comment: The error is shown in the toast.

Comment: Initialize your context variable in MyPhoneStateListener class, by passing in constructor or using broadcast reciver context as global var.

Answer (score 2):

Your context is not initialized. Either initialize context or instead of context try to use **"getApplicationContext()"** or **"getBaseContext()"**.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Or

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),msg , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The member field `context` in your class `MyPhoneStateListener` is never set. Initialize it with the current context.

```
[...]
//Create Listener
MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener(context);
[...]



private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener  {

    private Context mContext;

    private void MyPhoneStateListener() {
    }

    public void MyPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)  {

        Log.e("MyPhoneListener",state+"   incoming no:"+incomingNumber);

        if (state == 1) {
            String msg = "New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : "+incomingNumber;
            Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make Constructor for **MyPhoneStateListener**

```
Context mContext;
public void MyPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

Now use this mContext variable to in your Toast.

```
String msg = "New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : "+incomingNumber;
Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```